# mysqldump - redirect greped STDERR to a file

Tags: bash, grep, stdout, stderr

`mysqldump` generates STDOUT (used to dump *.sql), and also generates STDERR - that I need to filter + write to a file.

```
mysqldump --user=db_username --password=db_password --add-drop-database --host=db_host db_name 2>> '/srv/www/data_appsrv/logs/mysql_date_ym.log' > '/mnt/backup_srv/backup/daily/file_nm.sql'
```

The code above will write STDERR to `mysql_date_ym.log`

I need to exclude `Warning: Using a password` string from STDERR that is written to `mysql_date_ym.log`

I tried variations with `grep`, `2>>` and `>`, but none works.

Comment: If the warning message is part of stderr, the output will display on screen and not go to the log file

Comment: Just use `grep -v` to exclude pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
command 1>stdout.txt 2> >(grep -v "Thing to remove from stderr" >stderr.txt)
```

Which will redirect STDOUT to stdout.txt, and STDERR via process substitution into the grep filter, then finally to stderr.txt.

So your full command would look like this

```
mysqldump --user=db_username --password=db_password --add-drop-database --host=db_host db_name 1>'/mnt/backup_srv/backup/daily/file_nm.sql' 2> >(grep -v "Warning: Using a password" > '/srv/www/data_appsrv/logs/mysql_date_ym.log')
```

---

You could also use a sed script to run on the mysql_date_ym.log file after redirecting STDOUT/STDERR normally to the output files.

```
sed -i 's/Warning: Using a password//g' mysql_date_ym.log
```

Comment: complains about `2> >`: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

Comment: It should work, but your command would be `mysqldump --user=db_username --password=db_password --add-drop-database --host=db_host db_name 1>'/mnt/backup_srv/backup/daily/file_nm.sql' 2> >(grep -v "Warning: Using a password" > '/srv/www/data_appsrv/logs/mysql_date_ym.log')` also what version of bash are you using? Use `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to find that

Comment: Looks like it's working! is `1>` meant to write to STDOUT?

Comment: `1>` will redirect STDOUT not write to it. You don't need to include the 1, but I just did for readability.

Comment: I questioned as I was confused, you mentioned in your answer: STDIN.. so basically you meant STDOUT, right?

Comment: Ah that's my bad. It will redirect STDOUT, not STDIN. Fixed.

Comment: thanks a lot! could you post in the answer the command that you put in comments? so other would find that faster. Thanks again!

Comment: a quick question: I am trying to `gzip` the sql by adding `| gzip`: `mysqldump --user=db_username --password=db_password --add-drop-database --host=db_host db_name | gzip 1>'/mnt/backup_srv/backup/daily/file_nm.sql' 2> >(grep -v "Warning: Using a password" > '/srv/www/data_appsrv/logs/mysql_date_ym.log')`. But now grep is ignored, and 'Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.' appears on screen. How can it be fixed?

Comment: When you pipe, you're losing the original STDERR file descriptor and opening a new one with the gzip command (unless you do |&, but this will merge STDOUT and STDERR, so you won't be able to split them later). Instead what you should do is the same way you handled the STDERR fd originally: `mysqldump --user=db_username --password=db_password --add-drop-database --host=db_host db_name 1> >(gzip >'/mnt/backup_srv/backup/daily/file_nm.sql') 2> >(grep -v "Warning: Using a password" >'/srv/www/data_appsrv/logs/mysql_date_ym.log')` Though there is probably a better way to do it, this will work.